# FullCalendar week view without resources and event

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, fullcalendar

I have been spending whole day time to research on this but no luck. I wanted the fullcalendar to look like this:

```
           November
  <<  S  M  T  W  R  F  S  >>

      1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

In fullcalendar, I only able to do like this:
[image]

What I actually want is put the date in the box below.

If this can't be done using fullcalendar, does anyone know any other plugin which can do this?

Comment: what actually do you want? do you want to remove time and all day event's row?

Comment: you mean you just want a datepicker, or what? It's not really clear. fullCalendar is for displaying events...just like a calendar you might put on your fridge at home , or on the desk in your office. Just like the calendar in Outlook. If you just want a grid of dates to choose from then use a datepicker plugin, there are dozens available for free e.g. [this one](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/). If that's not what you want, you'll have to explain more clearly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ADyson Hi, sorry for the confusion, you can check [here](https://demo.mobiscroll.com/jquery/calendar/week-to-month#) , when you click inside this link choose "week", and that's what I want.

Comment: yeah that's basically just a datepicker as far as I can tell. So what's stopping you using that particular component directly?

Comment: @ADyson but what I want is only show 1 week only, when they click next or swipe then only show next week. Can jQuery datepicker do this?

Comment: You might be able to customise it a bit. But again, what's stopping you from using the exact plugin you linked to? It seems to already solve your problem.

Comment: @ADyson Because it's need to pay, I am looking for an open source plugin

Comment: Ok. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (which hopefully you did read when you signed up, as you were intended to when you took the tour). Asking for recommendations is off-topic on this site. See item 4 in that link for the (very sensible) reasons why. Sorry. You might have more luck on other forums.

Comment: @ADyson In the question, I do asked whether fullcalendar is able to such thing.

Comment: yes, and I already explained that the purpose of fullCalendar is something entirely different. It's not a datepicker, it's an event calendar. After that you then go on to ask for plugin recommendations, which is strictly off-topic.